# How to create a view using code in Drupal 7?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-views

We can create a view from  admin panel. But I want to create a view using php code. Can anyone show me the way?

Answer (score 7):

There is code floating around that wouldn't work for me. But This one did. Add this php to your .module file. Then create a views folder and then put all your views in there with the extension of .inc. Each view file will simply be `<?php` followed by the exact export of the view...

```
/**
* Implements hook_views_api().
*/
function MODULENAME_views_api() {
  return array ('api' => 3.0);
}

function MODULENAME_views_default_views() {
  // Check for all view file in views directory
  $files = file_scan_directory(drupal_get_path('module', 'MODULENAME') . '/views', '/.*\.inc$/');

  // Add view to list of views
  foreach ($files as $filepath => $file) {
    require $filepath;
    if (isset($view)) {
      $views[$view->name] = $view;
    }
  }

  // At the end, return array of default views.
  return $views;
}
```